# ¿Como puedo dirigirme a una web desde mi aplicación ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde tengo un botón que me debe dirigir a una web.

```
<button ion-button round icon-only>
    <a href="https://www.google.es/">
        <ion-icon name="logo-google"></ion-icon>
    </a>
</button>
```

Pero cuando doy click en este boton me sale lo siguiente:

```
Cannot GET /www.google.es/
```

¿como puedo hacer que funcione?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No lo puedes hacer directamente, tienes que usar un plugin **cordova-inappbrowser**.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

Esto en el .ts correspondiente

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController , Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

constructor( public platform: Platform,public navCtrl: NavController) 
{

}
openUrl(url) {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        let browser = new InAppBrowser();
        browser.create(url,'_blank');
    });
  }    
}
```

Y después en el .html

```
<button ion-button round icon-only (click)="openUrl('https://www.google.es/')">
    <ion-icon name="logo-google"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: estoy tratando de implementar lo que dices
pero me salieron dos errores, el primero es que no encuentra la clase InAppBrowser, pero ya lo solucione, la ruta esta mal escrita debe ser así from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser'; y el segundo error es new InAppBrowser("https://www.google.es/",'_blank'); se debe llamar primero el método constructor y luego pasarle los parametros en el método create("https://www.google.es/",'_blank'); y listo, gracias por la ayuda